# string new line with special charactoers is not working what I exepted

Tags: string, jenkins, cron

I just created a string such as

```
str =  "TZ=Europe/Berlin\n* * 1-5\n0 5 * * *\n"
```

I exepted that

```
TZ=Europe/Berlin
* * 1-5
0 5 * * *
```

in jenkins cron

but it was not working

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your chron expression doesn't appear valid. The validation error is "Day of month values must be between 1 and 31". Check it here: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Also check out https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/ for Jenkins specific help.